# Reading XML tags getting value from inner tag

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I don't know how to explain my situation, I can provide example below. 
I have an XML file to be read in Java, something like this:

```
<Author AffiliationIDS="Aff1">
    <AuthorName DisplayOrder="Western">
       <GivenName>Wei</GivenName>
       <GivenName>Long</GivenName>
       <FamilyName>
       <Value>Tan</Value>
       </FamilyName>
    </AuthorName>
</Author>
```

As you can see the `<FamilyName>` tag, inside the `<FamilyName>` tag is surrounded by a Value tag. This is because in the xsd it stated the element as `maxOccurs="unbounded"` which mean more than one value can be in that element tag. How should I modify the code so that it can read in the `<FamilyName>` tag and get `Value` tag element no matter how many occurrence of the `Value` exist?

Example:

```
           <FamilyName>
           <Value>Sarah</Value>
           <Value>Johnson</Value>
           </FamilyName>
```

The code look like this.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;

public class ReadXMLFile {

  public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("/fileaddress/test-1.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);


        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("AuthorName");

        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                System.out.println("Given Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("GivenName").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Family Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("FamilyName").item(0).getTextContent());

            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the FamilyName node by getElementsByTagName("FamilyName").item(0) and loop over its child nodes (.getChildNodes()) and get the value of the textNode

Or,

You can even getElementsByTagName("Value") if you are sure that value tag does not occur anywhere else other than inside FamilyName

Here is a code Sample

```
NodeList children = doc.getElementsByTagName("FamilyName").item(0).getChildNodes();

for(int i=0;i<children.getLength();i++) {
      if(children.item(i).getNodeType()== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element child = (Element)children.item(i);
            System.out.println(child.getTextContent());
       }
}
```

Comment: Its not possible to getElementsByTagName("Value") as other tag will have the same name call value if more than one occurrence allow.

Comment: Yes. That is what i have mentioned in the answer. You can try the first method (i.e loop over the children of FamilyName)

Comment: possible to get the name of the tag too? I am able to loop thur the getchildnodes() now.